# Contradicting Logs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If $\log(10^2)=2$

and $(\log10)^2=(1)^2=1$

Then

$10^{\log(10^2)}=10^2=100$

But what about

$10^{(\log10)^2}$ ?

We get 2 solutions:

A. $10^{(\log10)^2}=10^{\log10} \times 10^{\log10}=10^1 \times 10^1=100$

B. $10^{(\log10)^2}=10^{1^2}=10^1=10$

What gives ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed the fact that $$a^x a^y = a^{x+y},$$ not $$a^x a^y \ne a^{xy}.$$  Hence, in (A), $$10^{(\log 10)^2} \ne 10^{\log 10} 10^{\log 10} = 10^{2 \log 10}.$$

Comment: If 10^(4)^2=10^8=10^4 x 10^4, then 10^(log10)^2=10^log10 x 10^log10

Comment: @TomBeatrous  First, your notation is ambiguous because you are not using MathJax to typeset your equations.  Second, the convention is that when we write an expression like $$10^{4^2},$$, exponentiation proceeds in a top-down fashion:  That is to say, $$10^{4^2} = 10^{(4^2)} = 10^{16} \ne 10^8.$$  When you write 10^(4)^2, I have no way of determining whether you mean $(10^4)^2$ or $10^{(4^2)}$.  In your original example, you write 10^(\log 10)^2.  In (A), you treated this as $(10^{\log 10})^2$, but in (B), you treated it as $10^{((\log 10)^2)}$.  That is the essence of your contradiction.

Comment: Pretty interesting "contradiction"--TYSM for clearing it up.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$(a^x)^y \ne a^{x^y}$

(you have proved this fact)

Comment: +1 though perhaps more clearly that is an example of $(a^x)^y \not = a^{(x^y)}$ with $a^{x^y}$ by convention representing the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is "What gives?"

$$x^{(y^z)}\ne {(x^y)}^z$$

For example,

$$2417851639229258349412352=2^{(3^4)}\ne {(2^3)}^4=4096$$  This is essentially the fallacy in lines A. and B.. The logarithms obscure this.

Comment: And the former is $2^{81}$ while the latter is $2^{12}$, which explains the huge difference.